# Linq expression decimal culture

Tags: linq, subsonic3, expression, culture

I have this piece of code:

```
fee.SingleOrDefault(f => 100.05M >= f.Rate);
```

In the database the Fee.Rate is a money field stored using invariant culture. But using this select gives an error because my current culture will convert "100.05" to "100,05" wihich results in;

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Deleting my answer as it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Only thing I can think of right now:

- Swith currentculture to invariant
- Perform query
- Restore currentculture

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as less of a LINQ issue and more of a SubSonic issue. Taking a quick peek at their LINQ parser it looks like constant values are handled with ToString() with no regard for culture (see SubSonic.Linq.Structure.TSqlFormatter.VisitConstant). Writing/contributing a patch for this would be ideal (to either allow specification of a culture or at least to use invariant by default), otherwise I think you're stuck switching the thread culture.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. As a solution I have modified the SqlServer.ttinclude template to switch to invariant culture in the Find method.
Not a perfect but temporary solution, I'll create a patch or at least report the problem to SubSonic.